# Nesting Tables Using HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested

I'm trying to nest two tables inside of another table (so they'll display side by side, and I can add a third once I have enough information to do so. ) The "Sam's Painting Price Schedule" shows up without a problem, CSS intact and appropriately aligned. The second table I'm trying to nest within the second cell of the larger table does not. Instead, it shows up beneath the first nested table. I can't figure out why. I've looked at several threads on here, but everyone just is saying "don't nest tables"... So I tried not nesting them. But they still won't display side by side. Here's what I have:

```
<table class = "pricingTable" >
<tr>
<th colspan = "2">Sam's Painting<br>Price Schedule</th></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">11"x14" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$40</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">14"x17" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$80</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">16"x20" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$100</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">20"x20" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$120</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">18"x24" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$125</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">20"x32" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$150</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">36"x24" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$200</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan = "2">Bracelets</th></tr><tr>
<td  class = "pricingTable">Simple Bracelet</td><td  class = "pricingTable">$15</td>
</tr></table>

<table class = "pricingTable" ><tr>
<th colspan = "2">Chana's Sewing<br>Price Starter Guide</th>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Cravats </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$20</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Bow-ties </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$20</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Cuffs </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$30</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Skirts </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$35</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Bustles </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$40</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Coats</td><td  class = "pricingTable">$40</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">36"x24" </td><td  class = "pricingTable">$200</td></tr>
<tr><td  class = "pricingTable">Tie Tacks</td><td  class = "pricingTable">$10
</td></tr></table>
```

**In case it's pertinent, here's the "pricingTable" portion of the CSS.**

```
.pricingTable
{
    border:2px solid slategrey;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Saw that I had forgotten it right after I posted. Just finished the edit.

Comment: you have to put the other table inside the table.. now you have to separate tables

Comment: I separated them to try to get them to display side by side. The only visual difference with this version, is that there's a break between the top table and bottom table.

Comment: then use css table{width:45%;float:left;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table class="outer"><tr>
<td>put table 1 here</td>
<td>put table 2 here</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Dangit. I swear I tried that. I must have missed a tag somewhere when I did it. Thank you, taking that and putting the fully created tables into each section worked.

Comment: Awesome, yeah, keep it simple :P

Comment: You should mark this post as the right answer to follow the stack overflow standards

Comment: Was just waiting for it to let me. Takes ten minutes, and I had to cook dinner too. Accepted now. ;)

Comment: Sweet... haha you too.. making pasta here XD

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much do it 2 ways. By Inline block (make an elemenent like a div to envelop them and give it an inline block, creating an inline element next to each other) or you let them specificly float left and right.

```
<strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>
    <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    .inlineTable {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

or

```
<strong>Using float: left; </strong><br>
   <table border=1 class="floatedTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 class="floatedTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        .floatedTable {
            float:left;
        }
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SM769/

Also you can put them simply in an outer table, as described by Medda86.